# Windows Phone 8 scroll / tap issue with linked images

Tags: html, css, windows-phone-8, scroll, tap

I develop responsive website and I have some strange problem with Windows Phone 8 Internet Explorer. When I scroll page and accidentally tap linked image (in "slick slider"), browser redirect to new address. I read that issue appears on Lumia 1520, but I have Lumia 520 and my colleagues have other phone models - problem still appears.
Problem started to occur from some update - before that everything had worked well. There is any CSS or HTML hack for mobile IE? In addition, not all linked images break scroll.

Thanks

[Lumia 1520 scroll & tap bug](http://www.ibtimes.co.uk/nokia-lumia-1520-having-tap-scroll-bug-issue-fix-available-this-1460475)

Example code:

```
<!-- banner -->
        <div class="banner">
            <div class="slider">
                <div class="slide">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img data-lazy="temp/slide.jpg" alt="Tekst alternatywny slajdu" class="visible-xs" />
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="slide">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img data-lazy="temp/slide.jpg" alt="Tekst alternatywny slajdu" class="visible-xs" />
                    </a>
                </div>
                <div class="slide">
                    <a href="#">
                        <img data-lazy="temp/slide.jpg" alt="Tekst alternatywny slajdu" class="visible-xs" />
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
<!-- /banner -->
```

Answer (score 0):

There is some bug in newer versions of slick slider. 1.5.5 is the last version where scroll works fine on Windows Phone 8.